# Error getting the id of DefaultScheduleEvent Primefaces Schedule

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to "setId" and "getId" of an **DefaultScheduleEvent object**, I create the object and manually set the ID of the event (e.g. **15**) ,but when I try to get the ID (expecting to be the same I setted **15**) I got something like this: **c3e083a9-c418-4753-976c-801c0e9e6157**, which i believe is an object id,

Do you guys know why i dont get the id i setted?

I am using **primefaces 4.0**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after working on it for a while, I found a solution that worked for me. The problem is that the Id is assigned when you add the event to the event model. If you set the Id after it was added the the eventModel, it will keep the good Id.
Use:

```
private ScheduleModel eventModel;
private ScheduleEvent event;

event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(title, beginDate, endDate);
eventModel.addEvent(event); 
event.setId(clientEntity.getId());
```

Instead of

```
event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(title, beginDate, endDate);
event.setId(clientEntity.getId());
eventModel.addEvent(event);
```

Comment: What PF version did you do this with? If it also fails, file an issue in the PrimeFaces github that the '`addEvent(Event event)` method should check if the id is already set and if so check if it is unique and if not, throw an exception

Comment: Of course I also meant that if it was set and unique it should be left alone\

Comment: I'm using an early version of PF (3.5). I don't have much time to write a note. This solution did work for me however.

Comment: If you print out the id before and after adding it to the eventModel, the value is different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because there is no default constructor that takes id as a parameter.

```
public DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end)

public DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end, boolean allDay)

public DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end, String styleClass)

public DefaultScheduleEvent(String title, Date start, Date end, Object data)
```